Oracle utl_file and end of file character
On Monday we started having an issue with one of our email jobs.  The email body is generated using utl_file and sent using mailx.  The emails started having a .bin attachment containing the body.
After researching I discovered that for some reason utl_file started generating files using Hex 15 as the end of file character instead of 0A.
I implemented a work-around by stripping the HEX 15 character from the end of the file but it's bugging me why this is happening.
The files generated on the 14th look fine and the issue started on the 15th.  Our DB team says no changes were made over the weekend and I don't see any changes that were made on the server the job runs from.
Oracle version is "Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.20.0.0.0"
I tried running my test script from an old Solaris server and from SLES 12 with the same result.
I created a simple procedure to test.
create or replace PROCEDURE test_nl_email_issue (FNAME in varchar2) IS
  pathnm           varchar2(30)  := 'NL_UTL';
  com_id           UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  com_id := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(pathnm,'test_' || FNAME || '.txt','w');
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(com_id) THEN
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(com_id,'Line 1');
    UTL_FILE.PUT(com_id,'Test Message New');
    UTL_FILE.FFLUSH(com_id);
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(com_id);
  END IF;
END;


If I run this from my windows machine using sql developer the resulting file looks good.  It ends with a line feed character (0A) and sends fine.
00000000: 4c69 6e65 2031 0a54 6573 7420 4d65 7373  Line 1.Test Mess
00000010: 6167 6520 4e65 770a                      age New.

If I run this from my linux machine the resulting file ends with a HEX 15 character.
00000000: 4c69 6e65 2031 0a54 6573 7420 4d65 7373  Line 1.Test Mess
00000010: 6167 6520 4e65 7715                      age New.

If I change the final put in the test procedure to put_line both the 0A and 15 are added.
00000000: 4c69 6e65 2031 0a54 6573 7420 4d65 7373  Line 1.Test Mess
00000010: 6167 6520 4e65 770a 15                   age New..


what happens if you replace the utl_file.put with utl_file.put_line ?

"If I run this from my x machine" Clarify whether you mean when you connect to an instance on an x machine or if you mean you connect while the client connects from an x machine.

If I change my test to use put_line, the file ends with "0a 15"

@JeffHolt I telnet to my linux machine, connect to the db via sqlplus, then execute the test script.

@PaulW  I execute the test procedure using:  exec test_nl_email_issue('putline').  I said script, but meant procedure.

If the db server truly was and is a constant, then focus on changes that could've happened on the client machine, its toolchain, and its environment.

Verify that you are connecting to the same host with each test (SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') FROM  dual). Also compare your NLS settings  (SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters) and see if changing them (if they don't match) does anything.

0x15 being the NAK character and you are using telnet leads to the idea: can you try with ssh connection to compare?

@p3consulting Just tried and same thing.  The NAK is what's really throwing me.  I had our DB group ping my server from the DB and everything looks great.  Excellent response time and no dropped packets.

0x15 is NL (New Line) as the character combining the functions of line feed and carriage return... in EBCDIC...

I saw that too.  But why would oracle or utl_file generate an EBCDIC file when I run from a linux machine but ASCII when I run from SQL developer on my windows machine?

As Paul W, told you there must be something different in the local settings of the client: look at NLS values, including in the shell environment variables.

I'd like to thank Paul and Jeff for their thoughts on this issue.  It ended up being a configuration issue on the DB side.  From what I'm told:

There was an additional entry created in the listener.ora file
The listener was started manually instead of using the correct procedure
Because of the two issues above, there was a mismatch.  I guess oracle was trying to use the oracle 12 utl_file against the oracle 19 database.

It's still not clear to me why the issue started when it did as there were no scheduled patches and no outage that would have required restarting the listener.
It's working now though and I suppose that's the important thing.

Thanks for following up with the fix, but I feel like there's still more to this story. This seems like an NLS issue, but as far as I know the listener has nothing to do with NLS settings. And UTL_FILE is a package, not a separate program, which means it's always going to match the version of the database. (Unless an upgrade went horribly wrong.) It would be helpful if you could more precisely identify the issue so this answer could help future readers.
